# checked for angularjs not working properly for radio type input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple form for gathering text and choice data like -

**HTML** Form -

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Event Name<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Music Concert at Las Vegas" ng-model="event.name" required="required" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Is Active<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="radio" name="is_active" ng-model="event.is_active" value="yes" checked="checked" class="form-control">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="radio" name="is_active" ng-model="event.is_active" value="no" class="form-control">&nbsp;&nbsp;No
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my **controller** -

```
$scope.event.is_active = "yes";
```

Now the problem I am facing is -

1. If I remove the `$scope.event.is_active = "yes"` from the controller "Yes" option should remain works due to the presence of `checked="checked"` HTML attribute set, but it won't.
2. Now If I remove the `checked="checked"` attribute so whether do I have `$scope.event.is_active = "yes"` in my controller or not it won't work i.e not of the option is pre checked.

Let me know what I am missing with here with the angular way.

Comment: For 2). It works for me. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @runTarm `1.2.10` http://pastebin.com/3VZ2JBzu

Comment: I believe there is an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'is_active' of undefined`. You have to initialize the `event` object first or do it like this: `$scope.event = { is_active: 'yes' };`

Comment: @runTarm I believe this might be an issue due to JADE template which I am using as If I apply your above selection on PURE html form then its working but not on jade templates without the checked attribute usage

Comment: @runTarm You can check that this is my form in jade http://postimg.org/image/nom60jz6l/ not having checked option  and this is my controller thing thing http://postimg.org/image/6yo5g0r6x/ and u can check this is not working http://postimg.org/image/oekjbs5wn/